# Will connection pool keep oracle session staying active?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, connection-pooling

i have a question about connection pool and oracle database. if i set the min size of the connection pool to 5, does that means even when the app is idle, oracle database will still keep 5 sessions active? thanks!

Comment: I believe unless you specify the reap time, it will remain active.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it should keep connections even if app is idle. Good idea is to check if connection on pool is still alive. Wrappers like HikariCP/Commons DBCP handle such cases.

//edit
Connection pool wont start 5 connections on application start but it will initialize new connection if it will be needed. And of course pool can be set to shutdown connection after finishing operation on it.

Connection pool behavior doc [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/e10788/optimize.htm)